# protect files from editing in linux

Tags: c, linux, inotify

How do you protect a file from editing by an external program  or user , even if that user has somehow got root privileges. Let's say I have this File F which I have to protect and by default only the root and user can execute , read and write to F, all others only have read permission.

Let's say I have a program, which is protecting the critical file F, and detects that the circumstances of editing are unusual and seems like the security of the system may have been compromised. How to prevent saving changes to the File F ?If possible also kill that program which tried making that change.

I have found out that fuser can kill that process, but not before any modifications aka damage has been done. I use inotify to detect changes. My problem is most of the editors make a temporary file, make changes, and then save it to original file. Although I receive event like IN_OPEN, IN_CLOSENOWRITE and others, I get IN_CLOSEWRITE and IN_CLOSEMODIFY only after the event is complete ? How do I stop my file F From being modified ?

I understand that my program may be killed after someone gets into the system, but can I somehow save whatever little I can ?

Edit: I forgot to mention I can't change the permissions of any file which are monitored.

Edit #2: I have a set of files which have to be constantly monitored. My program would run in the background and note changes in those files. All files as I wrote earlier can be edited and executed by root, but there are actions(modifications) which may be undesirable and most probably would mean that someone has gained root access and has edited those critical files. I need to stop these harmful changes. From the answers I somehow presume that I will have to get a snapshot of those files. But the problem is the number of files could be huge , around 1 to 4 million. Any solutions which are efficient than snapshot solution are welcome.

Comment: I think it would be better to write a question describing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Make the file *immutable*: `chattr +i file_to_protect`. See `man chattr` for details.

Comment: pmg, I looked into chattr+i ,problem is the files which I must monitor may be deleted ie for some files it is a legal action, as for others it may vary, also data can be written to some files without deeming it as a harmful change.

Answer (score 2):

There is not way to protect the file if the "attacker" has root. Whatever you do, root can undo.
Having said that, if you want to make it hard, you could put the file on a readonly filesystem, such as a cdrom.

Comment: The question is not what can a root do or undo, what can a program do under such conditions, the program is supposed to be real-time, putting in cdrom is out of the question.

Comment: Maybe you should provide some additional info on what exactly you are trying to do, but it seems to me that once the file is written to there's little you can do about it.
Perhaps you could use some kind of LVM snapshotting to preserve a 'known good' version. Or use DragonlyBSD's hammer filesystem.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system for more about this kind of idea

Comment: I looked into versioning system, since I have never used one, can someone suggest looking into the requirements, a good versioning system(not versioning filesystem) which has an API that can be called from a c program. Looking at the responses, seems like there is undoing possible but Not prevention ?

Comment: I think you can't prevent anyone with write permissions from writing, the best you can do is rollback (assuming he does not simply destroy the backup too)

is http://libgit2.github.com/api.html suitable for what you need ?

Answer (score 2):

If root is malicious, there's no way to make any guarantees about data integrity. Ideally on such a critical system, nobody should have root whatsoever without taking the system offline and into a maintenance environment (possibly replacing it with a surrogate system while it's offline if constant uptime is critical).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do chattr+i (change attribute to immutable) to prevent even the root from editing the files. The root can always revert this, but you might be able to protect your file from a script-kiddie who does not know about chattr.

Answer (score 0):

You should either lock the file from your application or change it's [`ACL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) and [`RWX`](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html) rights

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't change the permissions of any file which are monitored

Answer (score 0):

What if your monitoring app obtained a lock on each file it is monitoring?  flock, fctnl for example might work.  Then, other applications would not be able to edit the file.

Not sure how this affects deletion (which you said might be valid).